# run multiple headless android emulators with appium-python for Mobile app Automation in AWS EC2 Instances

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, android-emulator, appium, ubuntu-22.04

I have to setup automation environment for mobile app in AWS EC2, here i need to run multiple headless emulators in an single EC2 instance.

Some blogs suggests to use AWS Bare Metal instances which having KVM...
some are saying Use docker in EC2 Instances.

i am going to run the emulators in the headless mode do i need the KVM in EC2 server..
I have no idea about how it works..
Any suggestions would be appriciated

I had tried with this [gist for installing headless emulator in ec2 instance](https://gist.github.com/atyachin/2f7c6054c4cd6945397165a23623987d)   my instance type was t2.medium it asks for KVM support but my instance didn't have that..
[this blog](https://medium.com/innovies-club/running-android-emulator-in-a-docker-container-19ecb68e1909)  explains about run android emulator conatainers within docker in EC2 Instances but with GUI.but there is no need for GUI for me i need only headless